# строки в python

Tags: python

Дана строка, содержащая русскоязычный текст. Найти количество слов, начинающихся с буквы "е"

Comment: split() startwith()

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста, что вы пробовали.

Comment: `len([i for i in words.split() if i.lower()[0] == "е"])`

Comment: `len([i for i in words.split() if i.lower().startswith("е")])`

Answer (score 1):

```
words = "яблоко строка егерь еще"
count = 0
for word in words.split(" "):
    if word.strip()[0] == 'е':
        count +=1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

***Пример:***

```py
string = '...'

result = len(list(filter(lambda s: s.lower().startswith('е'), string.split())))
print(result)
```

Comment: `sum(map(lambda s: s.lower().startswith('е'), string.split()))`

Answer (score -1):

```
str = 'еще две ели были срублены егерем'
print((' ' + str).lower().count(' е'))
```